# Opencart images on amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, opencart

I currently have setup an Elastic Beanstalk account, my website is connected to AWS's RDB and is running smoothly on an EC2 instance via an Elastic Load Balancer.

My problem is that Opencart stores its images in a relative directory '/image'. Because of the non-persistent nature of the EC2 instance, after a few days any images I upload to the website are deleted. (It is also takes a long time to make small updates via `eb deploy` due to the large quantity of image files that must be uploaded every time.

My solution to this was to use the amazon S3 bucket that was created when I created the Elastic Beanstalk. However, attempting to change the image directory folder to my S3 bucket `http://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeas-x-xxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazon.com/image` resulted in an error message from OpenCart on the admin panel. Stating that the image directory is 'not writeable.'

I guess I have two major questions here, how can I make it so the EC2 instance can properly read and write to the S3 bucket? Is there an alternative solution I should be using instead?

Prior to this, I used this opencart extension:
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7748&filter_search=cdn&page=1

However, as the author of it stated himself, the /images are still stored locally, only the cached files are stored on S3.

Thanks!

Comment: To quickly test access from EC2 to S3, assuming you assigned an IAM role to your EC2 instance when you launched it, would be to go to the IAM Console and add the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy to the EC2 instance's role.

Comment: As I did it through Elastic beanstalk, the IAM role was already assigned for me. I've attached the AmazonS3FullAccess policy to the EC2 instance but am still getting the same error stating that the path is not writeable.

Comment: Hey @kevinlerd have you found a solution to this?